# What type of ancient Chinese headgear is this and what more do we know about it?

Tags: ancient-china, fashion

[image]

This is [Zhao Bing, Emperor Bing of Song,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhao_Bing) the 18th and last emperor of the [Song Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_dynasty). Is this headgear a [Tongtianguan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Chinese_clothing)? And whatever type of headgear it is, what more do we know about it? What does it symbolism and who was authorized to use it?

Update: I found these two great resources but still can't figure out exactly which one it is: [A list of Guan, Jin, and other headwear](https://torguqin.wordpress.com/hanfu/hanfu-history/list/), and [A Social History of Medieval China, pg. 7](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=40elDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=Tongtianguan%20headwear&source=bl&ots=-9XUmhqESu&sig=ACfU3U0kQUDxFdeMd7ALY-rU7PXEOizv6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3qvK5273pAhWixYsBHZm2AaEQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Tongtianguan%20headwear&f=false).

Comment: I can't tell you about the headgear.  However, i can tell you a few facts about Zhao Bing.  1) he was the Huangdi or "emperor".  2) he lived for 7 years and so was young. 3) he died a tragic death 4) He is venerated as minor god at his tomb.  Allof these can affect what type of headgear he is depicted wearing.

Comment: To the OP. I am sorry my previous answer **could be** wrong after the re-research. Sorry.

Comment: @Kentaro Oh, OK. Thank you very much for your input anyway, it was very interesting and you introduced me to a new term. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for understanding. Even the Chinese experts at our country's Q&A site can't answer. Literally nobody. But a good question.

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/47475/1420

Answer (score -1):

When the emperor chooses one of his sons to be his heir, the emperor would personally clasp the headpiece around the heir's topknot and fix it in place with the appropriate hair-stick.
It's basically a crown so the closest equivalent is 
Wángguàn 
or cap/hat/crown

Comment: Please provide sources for your assertions. Thank you.